# Not able to type in keyboard of UITextField after app is backgrounded ios

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

Has anybody faced this.
My UITextfiled does not take what i type from keyboard after i background my app and come back again on same form and try to type in UITextfield using keyboard.

If i kill the app and open again, then it works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Your keyboard may not focus on your UITextfield any more when you go back.

Comment: If you touch the UITextField, can you then type from the keyboard? If so, you just need to make it the first responder again.